# Links on page don't seem to be working

Tags: javascript, html, css

First and foremost I would like to state that I am quite new to php.

I'm developing a site using XAMPP and I've got a bit of code that's spitting out values from a MySQL database onto a php page. The thing is, some of the  links don't seem to be working. In the browser they're not visible as links, when you hover over them the cursor remains as an  arrow. I checked the source code and all *seems* to be fine. I have been fiddling with the .htaccess file in the root folder, if that's got anything to do with it.

```
//This link works just fine
echo "<div class='catname'><a href='".ROOTLINK."$caturl' class='caturllink'>".$catname."</a></div> \n"; 

//These are not working
echo "<div class='cat_post main'> \n
<h1><a href='" . ROOTLINK . $posturl . "' class='cat_post_link' >".$title."</a></h1> \n
<a href='" . ROOTLINK . $posturl . "' ><img src='".ROOTLINK.$photourl."' /></a> \n
<p><a href='" . ROOTLINK . $posturl . "' class='cat_post_link' >".$text."</a></p> \n
<br class='clear' /> <!-- <<<<<<< VERY IMPORTANT --> \n
</div> \n";
```

The ROOTLINK variable is defined to be `http://localhost/`.

The source code looks like this:

```
<div class='catname'><a href='http://localhost/sport' class='caturllink'>SPORT</a></div>

<div class='cat_post main'> 
<h1><a href='http://localhost/sport/20140727120738-commonwealth-games-kick-off.php' class='cat_post_link' >Commonwealth Games kick off</a></h1> 
<a href='http://localhost/sport/20140727120738-commonwealth-games-kick-off.php' ><img src='http://localhost//images/test/phpB206-20140727120738.jpg' /></a> 
<p><a href='http://localhost/sport/20140727120738-commonwealth-games-kick-off.php' class='cat_post_link' >Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vivamus faucibus nunc eleifend nunc sodales tempor. Nullam non enim risus. Praesent vel ante id diam venenatis tincidunt. Vivamus scelerisque, purus ac volutpat blandit, massa nunc feugiat justo, ut iaculis massa nibh at neque. Nunc id quam ut turpis blandit viverra. Nam sagittis, mi ut pulvinar posuere, diam ligula posuere  &hellip;</a></p> 
<br class='clear' /> <!-- <<<<<<< VERY IMPORTANT --> 
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
div.cat_post.main { display: block; border-bottom:2px solid #BE420E; padding-bottom: 15px; margin-bottom: 10px; }
div.cat_post.main img { width: 300px; height: 169px; background-color: #AAA; float: left; margin-right:10px;} 
div.cat_post.main p { float: right; width: 300px; height: 169px; margin: 0 10px 0; }
a.cat_post_link { color: #666666; }

.catname { background-color: #FFF68F; font-size: 24px; color: #BE420E;  margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px 5px 5px 10px; font-weight: bold;}
.caturllink { background: inherit; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Comment: Maybe you should show your CSS. Sounds like it has something to do with that, certainly not htaccess. Neither really with PHP and MySQL.

Comment: Is that the **exact** HTML output by PHP? Because that is valid and working HTML. If I copy that into an empty html file, all links work fine (except, of course, the target locations don't exist on my localhost). In that case, this is a client-side issue (perhaps caused by CSS or JavaScript or something else), not a server-side issue (i.e. a PHP or .htaccess issue).

Comment: Does this much CSS suffice? @putvande

Comment: "The thing is, some of the links don't seem to be working. In the browser they're not visible as links" What do you mean, exactly? Are they clickable? Do they take you to the correct page? What does "not visible as links" mean?

Comment: @Nic Did a Ctrl+U , got it from there.

Comment: @MattGibson They're not clickable. Although while the page loads strangely they are clickable. Once the page loads completely, they're not clickable anymore.

Comment: @Skittle "Once the page loads completely, (...) they're not clickable anymore" that sounds like a JavaScript issue. Definitely not a PHP / Apache (.htaccess) issue. You are probably loading some JavaScript that is disabling the links.

Comment: If they're clickable when the page loads, but not when it loads "completely", it may be a Javascript issue. As [you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/c9Bmd/), your posted code works fine, and links are clickable. You've got something else going on, and you need to debug it. We can't be much help if you can't narrow down the problem more than you have so far. I'm also going to remove some of the less likely tags from your question; this has nothing to do with MySQL, for example.

Comment: @Skittle If it's any help, the way I'd go about debugging is to use your browser's web inspection tools to try to figure out why the links are changing. I'd also remove any scripts from the page, then add them back one at a time to see if I could see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that the closing `</div>` tag in the sidebar was missing, once I re-added it everything went back to normal. Simple, yet detrimental.

Comment: Thanks for all your patience though peeps.